# How to get unique token from OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am building a service in which users do not have to create an account to sign up, but use Google account as exactly does Stackoverflow.com

My Question is there is any unique information of an user in OAuth2 which never change, so I can use it as user id in my database.

After looking through Google OAuth2 API, I've ended up that all tokens are arbitrary every time session is established.

I would like to know how such sites as Stackoverflow extract the user information to sign up.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the initial access token use the `tokeninfo` endpoint to get `user_id`.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" +
     Uri.EscapeDataString(response.AccessToken))
```